# while requesting session in uber rides it is showing csrf error.and how to get the redirect url in python without going and pasting the url to browser

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, uber-api

```
from collections import namedtuple
from yaml import safe_load

from uber_rides.client import UberRidesClient
from uber_rides.session import OAuth2Credential
from uber_rides.session import Session

from builtins import input

from yaml import safe_dump

import utils  
from example.utils import import_app_credentials

from uber_rides.auth import AuthorizationCodeGrant
from uber_rides.client import UberRidesClient
from uber_rides.errors import ClientError
from uber_rides.errors import ServerError
from uber_rides.errors import UberIllegalState



CREDENTIALS_FILENAME = 'config.rider.yaml'

# where your OAuth 2.0 credentials are stored
STORAGE_FILENAME = 'session_store.yaml'

filename=CREDENTIALS_FILENAME
with open(filename, 'r') as config_file:
    config = safe_load(config_file)
client_id = config['client_id']
client_secret = config['client_secret']
redirect_url = config['redirect_url']

credentials = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'redirect_url': redirect_url,
    'scopes': set(config['scopes']),
}


auth_flow = AuthorizationCodeGrant(
    credentials.get('client_id'),
    credentials.get('scopes'),
    credentials.get('client_secret'),
    credentials.get('redirect_url'),
)

auth_url = auth_flow.get_authorization_url()
print(auth_url)

session = auth_flow.get_session("http://127.0.0.1/?state=AWBraIpW7HErfj2pMl0RTV4G1gN93yDN&code=7KyJcFsWk68ZHRjUGuOyR571Y75NPk#_")
client = UberRidesClient(session, sandbox_mode=True)
credential = session.oauth2credential

with open(storage_filename, 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml_file.write(safe_dump(credential, default_flow_style=False))
```

---

**output:+++++++ERROR+++++++++++++++**

```
https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?scope=profile+places+request+request_receipt+all_trips+history&state=dO0Lo8gjVuTdIZo6UPIOfFpWKmQ133xu&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2F&response_type=code&client_id=Ws4Za7kSxIdQdpxcZnL2WC9L8NVl3UBT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ride.py", line 53, in <module>
    session = auth_flow.get_session("http://127.0.0.1/?state=AWBraIpW7HErfj2pMl0RTV4G1gN93yDN&code=7KyJcFsWk68ZHRjUGuOyR571Y75NPk#_")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uber_rides/auth.py", line 294, in get_session
    authorization_code = self._verify_query(query_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uber_rides/auth.py", line 255, in _verify_query
    raise UberIllegalState(error_message)
uber_rides.errors.UberIllegalState: CSRF Error. Expected dO0Lo8gjVuTdIZo6UPIOfFpWKmQ133xu, got AWBraIpW7HErfj2pMl0RTV4G1gN93yDN
```

Comment: Improved content formatting

Answer (score 2):

In this case authorization code and state code does not match, here is explanation...

When posting request for authorization URL as it is done in this part of .py file:

```
 auth_url = auth_flow.get_authorization_url()
 print(auth_url)
```

URL is pasted into a browser and acceptance is done manually.

Lately, response url containing state code is hard-coded in Python app as it is done in this part of .py file:

```
 session = auth_flow.get_session("http://127.0.0.1/?state=AWBraIpW7HErfj2pMl0RTV4G1gN93yDN&code=7KyJcFsWk68ZHRjUGuOyR571Y75NPk#_")
```

Any further execution of Python app will post request for another Authorization URL, so the state code changes along with it. More information about integrating Uber API requests into Python code can be found [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk).

You will need to figure out a way to automate authorization process and transferring *.get_session* url within single .py-code iteration.